# C# and Crystal Reports SDK - Selection Criteria Ignored

Tags: c#, sdk, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal reports rpt file being called from C# code. Report works as expected from Designer within Studio 2010. Same report ignores Selection Criteria when called from C#, but ONLY when including a certain table's field in the criteria.

**Current Criteria Example :**

```
date({transaction.transaction_date}) in {?FromTo} and   
{user_branch.branch_id} = 1
```

{?FromTo} is a date range parameter which works perfectly

When I remove the branch_id section, the {?FromTo} date parameter is checked correctly and the data returns as expected. BUT, as soon as I include the branch_id field, ALL the data is returned, which does not make sense at all.

Running this exact same report via the designer, works correctly... The problem occurs when running via C# SDK code.

Any help with this will be GREATLY appreciated

**Already Tried**

- Recreate Entire Report from Scratch bit by bit, table by table. This works up to a point where I start adding more fields to the report itself, no one in particular, then the problem starts up again... So obviously, I start back tracing my steps until the entire report is empty again, but the problem persists, like the file is now "broken"
- No similar issues in google... No where in my code is a line emptying the selection criteria during code... My other reports not accessing that table works fine.
- Currently using version 13.0.1 of the CR Runtime. Tried to upgrade to 13.0.2, still didn't work
- Ran the exact same SQL that the report generated directly against the database. That works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many head-aches this week, I finally found the problem... This looks like a bug in the SDK itself though, but to solve the problem, just make sure that the field giving the problem mentioned above is contained in the detail section of the report.

i.e. I added my branch_id field to the detail section of the report and suppressed it. It works by suppressing the section as well, just as long as the field is contained there.

I tested this on all my other reports with the same problem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your criteria to:

```
(date({transaction.transaction_date}) in {?FromTo}) and   
{user_branch.branch_id} = 1
```

Adding the `date({transaction.transaction_date}) in {?FromTo}` line inside a **`()`**.
 I'm not just sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Tried that, not working... 

I also removed the Date fields completely, only containing the branch_id field... still it returns data from branches 2 and 3 as well.

Comment: What is the connection of `transaction` table and `user_branch` table and how do you use them in one crystal report?

Comment: transaction.user_branch_id inner join user_branch.user_branch_id. The transaction is posted by a user logged into a certain branch, it's that branch the report is being generated for.

I've double checked and played around with the joins as well (outside the norm), but still no luck